# How to fix EOFException?

Tags: java, android

The code runs fine on IDE but whenever I implement it onto an application (for Android), it keeps giving me an **EOFException**.

this is the code:

```
try {
  URL url = new URL(link);

  URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
  BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  String inputLine;

  while ((inputLine = bf.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(inputLine);
  }

  bf.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

this is the **stacktrace**:

```
java.io.EOFException
W/System.err:     at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:95)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:179)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:101)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:628)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:409)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:353)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:220)
W/System.err:     at com.example.unknown.api_testing.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:45)
W/System.err:     at com.example.unknown.api_testing.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:35)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Can you share with us what the actual link is?

Comment: The server isn't sending a response: instead it is just closing the connection. This isn't something you can 'fix' at this end, unless you're using the wrong URL. Try it in a browser.

Comment: Can you share full code?

Comment: @madhankumar Why? The code he's posted should be sufficient, especially as the problem is at the other end.

Comment: Have a look at this post, the issue seems too occur for people using okhttp: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1114

Answer (score -1):

This could be due to the connection on your device. Are you running on WiFi or a 3G connection?

Your device may be losing the connection or dropping some packets. It may be worth running a QOS test to ensure that the connection is running well.

Have a look at an app such as: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nperf.tester&hl=en_GB

You may also want to check that the connection is correctly returning an END HTTP and not throwing an ERROR after it. Output each `inputLine` to your console while processing it to check for anything unusual.

You may also want to adjust your try catch block to correctly close the reader if an exception is thrown. Also be more specific with your catch blocks, for example: catch `IOException` and not `Exception` as this will allow you to handle these cases cleaner as you may want to handle `IOExceptions` differently from other `Exceptions`.

```
try 
{
    URL url = new URL(link);

    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = bf.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        sb.append(inputLine);
    }
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
finally 
{
    //close your reader here
    bf.close();
}
```

Comment: Running on Wi-Fi and internet connection is running smoothly, It only seems to work whenever I run it on IntelliJ, it fetches the HTML. If I attempt to use the code on my phone that's the only time I receive this error :( It works fine on my phone if i use a different link though.

Comment: No it couldn't be due to the local device. The local device has received a TCP FIN, *ergo* it is working correctly.

Comment: @EJP - How do you know the local device received a TCP FIN and that everything is working correctly?

Answer (score -3):

After the line:
            URLConnection con = url.openConnection();

put this line in orger to avoid receiving gzip response.

```
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity"); // no gzip
```